# linux command to read/monitor events from systemd-journald

Tags: systemd-journald

I want to monitor the events and logs of systemd-journal. Didn't find any commands i can use for the same. I am looking for something like 'tail -100f' which can show me the decoded events of systemd-journal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `journalctl` utility displays logs from systemd units. `systemd-journal` is a system unit. Therefore, you can use the following:

```
$ journalctl --unit systemd-journald --lines 100 --follow
```

Tested on CentOS 7.5

Comment: I'm glad it worked. One tip: this question belongs to serverfault.com.

Comment: oh okay. I will ensure this next time then :)

Comment: 2023 - Pls note that journalctl cannot be used to tail a apache error log unless mod_journald is installed but is not advised as this will be performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

```
journalctl -u gunicorn | tail -n 100
```